# When and where was “portfolio career“ first used?

Tags: etymology

The expression [portfolio career](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/portfolio-career) meaning:

> the fact of having several part-time jobs at once, rather than one full-time job:

> - A portfolio career is suitable for people who want to have a variety in their work life.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Etymonline has no information about the origin of the above expression, can anyone tell me when and where it was first used?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because .

Comment: *Portfolio career* is not an entry itself, but *portfolio* first used as an attributive is associated with Charles Handy, and the earliest attributive usage example is: 1984   C. HANDY *Future of Work* 173   *The portfolio flexilives that are likely to be forced upon us by the changing future of work may push us into discovering that we all have unused capacities within us.*

Comment: Duplicate question.

Comment: @Gigili because?

Comment: @marcellothearcane: Haha, I probably have accidentally hit delete which resulted in such a brilliant and thorough comment! The question as originally stated (it is edited now) was a demand to look up the word for the poster and made no sense to me.