# When was “portfolio career“ first used?

Tags: etymology

The expression portfolio career meaning:

the fact of having several part-time jobs at once, rather than one full-time job:

•   A portfolio career is suitable for people who want to have a variety in their work life.
(Cambridge Dictionary)

Can anyone tell me when and where it was first used?

Comment: If you're not happy with the answers you got when you asked this a few days ago, ***raise the matter on the original post*** - don't just ask the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly  1 January 1997.

> From job for life to portfolio career Dawn Johnson had worked in a
> national government office for 18 years when she was made redundant as
> part of its restructuring programme. She had risen to the position of
> head of marketing and publicity ...
>
> *[Creating your Career](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PKJ7T5PIwUsC&pg=PA7&dq=%22portfolio%20career%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMxpXvzbjqAhV8QkEAHdGODSU4HhDoATAEegQIBBAC#v=onepage&q=%22portfolio%20career%22&f=false)* - by Simon Kent 1997

---

**[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22portfolio%20career%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1997,cd_max:2003,lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk0223QjYnE1U6_3bulWxv_gs8tDygQ:1594037719737&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_paygzbjqAhUUh1wKHTqvCyUQpwUIIA&biw=1280&bih=591&dpr=1.5)** shows the usage in date order (latest first).

Comment: [***Handy (1989)** reported on the emergence of the “**portfolio worker**” and the “**portfolio career**,” where individuals maintain portfolios of their skills, abilities, and achievements...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+portfolio+career+where%22) But I can't find that original "Handy" text - the earliest I could easily pick out in print from Google Books was 1993.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think I can track it down, the book is http://content.time.com/time/specials/packages/article/0,28804,2086680_2086683_2086684,00.html, and I believe I can connect it with the quote. I'll have to delay until later due to IRL happenings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I did a quick search. It seems that Handy used the phrase "portfolio life" and this was in the context of careers. However I couldn't find the actual phrase "portfolio career" in his book.

Comment: Well, even if the specific original source of this "neologistic" usage only explicitly referenced *portfolio **worker***, it would be trivial to extend it to *portfolio **career***. What counts is when did someone first think of using the word "portfolio" in relation to "work **type**" rather than "work **output samples**".

Comment: ...I've just realised this is a straightforward duplicate (double-posted by the same OP)! Apparently [the earliest attributive usage example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539573/when-and-where-was-portfolio-career-first-used#comment1321836_539573) was already posted 2 days ago. But I can't be arsed to look at it, since apparently the OP here isn't satisfied with that answer anyway.